# How to access R user defined function with h2o.addFunction in H2O environment?

Tags: r, h2o

I am using r package of h2o 2.8.4.4. According to documentation function h2o.addFunction pushes user defined function and existing R functions in h2o. 
e.g.

```
>library(h2o)
>localH2O = h2o.init()
>h2o.addFunction(localH2O, function(x) { 2*x + 5 }, "simpleFun")
```

Now, How to access this function simplefun from within R or from h2o browser UI, because i am unable to find the function even with the list command

```
>h2o.ls(localH2O)
```

Output:   list()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the function from R like you normally would. by the way, there's no h2o.addFunction in H2O's latest H2O-3 (functions just work like magic).

Here's an example:

```
   apply(fr,2, function(x) { 2*x + 5 })
```

Or:

```
    simpleFun <- function(x) { 2*x + 5 }
    apply(fr, 2, simpleFun)
```